# Cache and Read Files in Specific Order

Tags: node.js, architecture, drag-and-drop, filesystems, fs

I'm creating an application in which users can create notes that are displayed in a grid. When a note is created, a corresponding text file is also created. When a user opens the application, the application reads the directory of note files, retrieves the content of each note file, and then displays it in the grid.

[image]

The idea is to make the grid of notes rearrangeable via drag-and-drop.

[image]

I've never done anything this before, so I'm struggling to devise an efficient way to cache or remember the order in which the user has arranged the notes. I thought of storing the position of each note in the filename itself.

`1_note3.txt`
`2_note7.txt`
`3_note4.txt`
`4_note2.txt`
`5_note6.txt`
`6_note8.txt`
`7_note5.txt`
`8_note1.txt`

This doesn't seem like a good approach since, anytime the the notes are rearranged, I'll have to rename a bunch of the files. For example, say the user creates a new note — which would be inserted as the first child of the grid for the sake of user experience — all of the filenames would have to be renamed.

***`1_note9.txt`***
`2_note3.txt`
`3_note7.txt`
`4_note4.txt`
`5_note2.txt`
`6_note6.txt`
`7_note8.txt`
`8_note5.txt`
`9_note1.txt`

Further, say a user now rearranges the notes by moving the first note to the fourth position in the top row. I'd now have to rename that file and all of the following files.

`2_note3.txt`
`3_note7.txt`
`4_note4.txt`
***`5_note9.txt`***
`6_note2.txt`
`7_note6.txt`
`8_note8.txt`
`9_note5.txt`
`10_note1.txt`

I could also store the order or arrangement in a separate file, and exclusively manipulate the content of this file instead of the actual filenames.

`arrangement.txt`

```
note3.txt
note7.txt
note4.txt
...
```

Although this may be superior to the last approach, it also doesn't seem that great since there is still additional overhead. For instance, when the application is launched, I'll first have to read that file in order to obtain the user arrangement before sorting files accordingly.

**Does anybody have any experience implementing something like this? Is there a better way to go about it?**

Answer (score 1):

You may like to maintain state of your note grid in a key-value map data structure. you can cache this map in-memory or persist it in a separate file. This key-value map will store note grid data where "Key" will have position order in the grid and "Value" will have name of the corresponding text file. In case notes are rearranged you only need to update value of two keys.

Comment: i completely forgot about mapping. ill give it a look tomorrow.